# ROSBC save data into SQL server

Tags: sql, r, append, rodbc

I'm trying to insert a data frame into an existing (empty) data table in a Microsoft SQL server using rodbc. The following code fails at the sqlSave stage:

```
# connect to SQL server
require(RODBC)
close(ch)
ch <- odbcConnect(dsn=...)

# list tables available in database
sqlTables(ch, schema = "dbo")

# get info on table structure
tmp <- sqlColumns(ch, "Currency")
varT <- as.character(tmp$TYPE_NAME)
names(varT) <- as.character(tmp$COLUMN_NAME) 

# this does not work
sqlSave(ch, df, tablename = "Currency", append = TRUE, rownames = FALSE, 
    varTypes=varT, verbose = TRUE, test = FALSE, nastring = NULL,  fast = TRUE)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in sqlSave(ch, df, tablename = "Currency", append = TRUE, rownames = FALSE,  : unable to append to table ‘Currency’
```

Here's the complete error message:

> sqlSave(ch, df, tablename = "Currency", append = TRUE, rownames = FALSE, 
>   +         varTypes=varT, verbose = TRUE, test = FALSE, nastring = NULL,  fast = TRUE)
>   Query: INSERT INTO "Currency" ( "CurrencyID", "Currency", "CountryID", "InvertSpot" ) VALUES ( ?,?,?,? )
>   Binding: 'CurrencyID' DataType 4, ColSize 10
>   Binding: 'Currency' DataType -8, ColSize 3
>   Binding: 'CountryID' DataType 4, ColSize 10
>   Binding: 'InvertSpot' DataType 4, ColSize 10
>   Parameters:
>   no: 1: CurrencyID 2/***/no: 2: Currency ARS/***/no: 3: CountryID 1/***/no: 4: InvertSpot 0/***/
>   sqlwrite returned 
>   [RODBC] Failed exec in Update
>   23000 547 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Currency_Country". The conflict occurred in database "GlobalMacro", table "dbo.Country", column 'CountryID'.
>   01000 3621 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The statement has been terminated. Query: DROP TABLE "Currency"
>   Error in sqlSave(ch, df, tablename = "Currency", append = TRUE, rownames = FALSE,  : 
>     unable to append to table ‘Currency’

Any recommendations on how to fix this? Thank you

Comment: I assume you've checked you actually have permission to access it? It's sort of hard for us to replicate without a dataset ;).

Comment: right - i can write to the server and create a new table using sqlSave. i just can't seem to populate an existing table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, that's your problem, buried in the expanded error message - "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Currency_Country". In other words, Currency_Country is a foreign key - something being referenced by your table from another table. As a result, trying to overwrite it is going to cause your query to error out, because a foreign key cannot contain data in table2 (where you're using it as a foreign key) that isn't in table1 (where it's actually contained).

You need to either (a) stop using a foreign key or (b) incorporate this data into the table that the foreign key originates in before attempting to insert it here.